# Setting custom properties on an 365 group with GraphClient

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I want to set CustomProperty5 on a 265 group. I have following code:

```
var extensions = await graphClient.Groups["xxx"].Extensions.Request().GetAsync();

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dictionary.Add("CustomAttribute5", "Works!");

await graphClient
.Groups["xxx"]
.Request()
.UpdateAsync(new Microsoft.Graph.Group()
{
AdditionalData = dictionary

});
```

However I get following error:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: Request_BadRequest Message:
>   One or more property values specified are invalid.

Any pointers how to set custom properties on a 365 group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For existing group [open extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-open-users) could be [updated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-open-users#3-change-roaming-profile-information) like this via `msgraph-sdk-dotnet`:

```
 //retrieve an existing group custom property   
 var ext = await graphClient.Groups[groupId].Extensions[extName].Request().GetAsync();

 //update
 ext.AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
 {
      {
          "status", "Closed"
      }
 };            
 await graphClient.Groups[groupId].Extensions[extName]
         .Request()
         .UpdateAsync(ext);
```

---

When it comes to [complex type extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-schema-groups), it could be updated via group update endpoint.  Lets assume the following type extension is registered:

```
{
    "id":"contoso_grpstatus",
    "description": "",
    "targetTypes": [
        "Group"
    ],
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "Status",
            "type": "String"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then an existing group instance with the `contoso_grpstatus` complex type extension defined could be updated like this:

```
var group = new Group
{
     AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
     {
          {
                "contoso_grpstatus", new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    {"Status", "Closed"}
                }
          }
     }
};
await graphClient.Groups[groupId]
         .Request()
         .UpdateAsync(group);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Så Status is a property on contoso_grpstatus that you set to Closed?

Comment: It is the built in attribute on 365 groups I am trying to set, I need to figure out how to transform this to that specific attribute.

Comment: That's right, both property name and value are specified

Comment: I tried following where xxx is my groupid. That did not work:       var group = new Microsoft.Graph.Group
            {
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    {
                        xx", new Dictionary<string, object>()
                        {
                            {"CustomAttribute5", "Works"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            await graphClient.Groups["xxx"]
                     .Request()
                     .UpdateAsync(group);